# stringByStandardizingPath EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, spritebuilder

I am using Cocos2D 3.1 and I am also using SpriteBuilder 1.1 to make a game for the iPhone. In one of my ccbi's however, every time I try to load it and present it on screen there is a crash in Cocos2D's `CCFileUtils.m` in the `standarizePath` method.

The `NSString *ret = [path stringByStandardizingPath];` line below is the line that it crashes on and all it says is that it is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I use ARC in my app and so does Cocos2D so I am not sure how to fix this. Here is the method:

```
-(NSString*) standarizePath:(NSString*)path
{
    NSString *ret = [path stringByStandardizingPath];
    if( _searchMode == CCFileUtilsSearchModeSuffix )
        ret = [self removeSuffixFromFile:ret];

    return ret;
}
```

How would one fix this crash? I am not even sure where to begin because my other views work perfectly fine!

Comment: how do you create and pass path? I'm guessing path pointer is not a valid string pointer

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It definitely is not nil. It returns an image name every time and the last logged image is definitely in the app bundle. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The culprit was a CCScrollView, as soon as I removed it from the view in SpriteBuilder and updated the ccbi, it didn't crash. Any reason for this?